# Why isn't my shader showing?

Tags: shaders

(Im somewhat new to blender)Why cant i see the brass material anywhere?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please elaborate. I can see a brass-like material in your screenshot pretty well. One sentence and random screenshots without further explanation rarely make a good question. What exactly do you expect to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to tell the Viewport to actually display textures/materials. Currently it's rendering "solid" which is often the best option to model (Some prefer MatCap)

To solve this, select Texture or Material in the highlighted dropdown:
[image]